# Using the shell of neo4j and the neo4j-shell-tools with jqassistant

Tags: neo4j, jqassistant, neo4j-shell

I am using jqassistant 1.2.0 with asciidoc 1.5.3 - all in maven. My question is a specific question for the maven plugin "jqassistant". I am scanning a xml file.

I want to use Neo4j shell tools (see: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools). These are a extension to the usual provided shell commands of the neo4j-shell. Using these in neo4j without jqassistant works well.

Now i want to use these commands with a store that was created from jqassistant. Simply using: 
"/bin/neo4j-shell.bat -path \jqassistant\store"
gives this error: 
"Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory"

So my question is: 
Is there a way to start the shell of neo4j on a jqA store OR: is there a way to start the neo4j shell FROM jqA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the server of jqassistant first before accessing the store on disk.

You *might* be able to run jqassistant's server with a config option that enables remote shell, 
then you can connect to the running server just by calling `bin/neo4j-shell`

Comment: Sadly there's currently no way to set config options for the embedded server except bindings for host and port. Things may become a bit easier with upcoming 1.3 release of jQAssistant which supports connecting to standalone installations of Neo4j 3.x databases for scan and analyis.